# Why this field after checkbox field always float on right?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

In one angular application, I am looping over the list of form fields to display them in grid as per their nature. For example if the field needs to be full width in the grid, its width is 98% and if it is half of the width in the grid, its width is 47%. Now everything works as expected shown in the image below, but not the field after any checkbox.

[image]

Here you can see that those who needs to be half width works perfectly but the Interest Rate field after Credit Cales checkbox field is floating always on the right Even though there is same style applied as other fields.

Here is the style for the class .example-width-2 which is used for half width elements.

```
.example-width-2 {
    width: 47%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

And here is the html markup for to generate all the fields in the loop.

```
 <div *ngFor="let input1 of formdata.properties">   
     <div>
          <mat-form-field class="example-width-{{input1.colmptypeid}}">
          <input matInput   type="text"  placeholder="{{input1.title}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here {{input1.colmptypeid}} is either 1 or 2 for full-width or half-width. I really don't know why it is happening only with the fields after checkbox.